# How can I pass parameters from an array as distinct arguments to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

Is there a way to translate an array of values into function arguments without having to change the function to accept a single array?

My case is I need to load portions of my webpage dynamically (I'm using jquery .load to do this) and when the load is complete I need to call a function with arguments. The problem is the callback functions have differing numbers of arguments and I'd rather not have to rewrite each function to accept a single argument object.

```
function f(a, b){ 
  // does stuff 
}

function g(a, b, c){ 
  // does other stuff 
}


function Bootstrap(DivNameToLoad, Callbackname, CallbackArgs){
    // Callbackname is a string name of the function to be called when load is complete
    // CallbackArgs is a [] with the values to be passed to the callback function

    $('#' + DivNameToLoad + 'PlaceholderDiv').load(DivNameToLoad + '.html', function(){

        // Call the callback function
        window[CallbackName](CallbackArgs); // This is where I have a problem
    });
}

//Call the bootstrap function and callback f passing in the values 'alpha' and 'bravo' for a and b
Bootstrap('SomeDiv', 'f', ['alpha', 'bravo']);

//Call the bootstrap function and callback g passing in the values 'alpha', 'bravo' and 'charlie' for a, b and c
Bootstrap('SomeDiv', 'f', ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie']);
```

It wouldn't surprise me if this wasn't possible, but maybe someone knows a clever way to do this?

Comment: Yup, this is a duplicate. Sorry, @Barmar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Function.apply()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp) method

```
window[CallbackName].apply(null, CallbackArgs);
```